# Vending Machine Transaction logs

Tags: data-request

Can anyone help me find/locate/create transaction logs for a vending machine?

How it records or structure sale of the product?
How does it store empty rows?

This is my first post in this forum....let me know if I have missed anything here.

Comment: Which protocol are you using? MDB? CCtalk? Something else?

Comment: I am just interested in logs, even if its a txt file dump it will work for me.

Comment: The ting is that different systems, such as MDB, CCTalk, etc, have different formats for reporting transactions. From me memory, for MDB, look in the spec for DEX (Data Exchange); there is a similar section in the CCTalk spec. Which protocol are you interested in?

Comment: I am okay to use MDB